# Why is this way of calculating variance incorrect?

Tags: probability, expectation, variance

Each morning John eats some eggs. On any given morning, the number of eggs he eats is **equally likely** to be 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 independent of what he has done in the past. Let *X* be the number of eggs that John eats in 10 days. Find the mean and variance of *X*.

---

I didn't have trouble with the mean:

$E(X) = [\frac{1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5}{5}] * 10 = 3 * 10 = 30$ (multiplying by 10 because of 10 days)

Now for the variance...

$var(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$

$E(X^2) = [\frac{1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2}{5}] * 10^2 = 11 * 100 = 1100$ (multiplying by 10 because of 10 days, **right?**)

$var(X) = 1100 - 30^2 = 200$

:)

edit: Solved

Comment: for $E(X^2)$ your $10$ must be squared, too. Edit: somehow your $30$ became a $35$, no idea why. (yielding a result of $200$)

Comment: Variance can never be negative.  Check your arithmetic.

Comment: @Max Got it! I'm getting 200 now, correct? Also it's 30, I mistyped

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: Please write up your solution as an answer and accept it so the question doesn't remain marked as unanswered.